# Use predefined index if none detected?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, indexing

I made an auto file indexer in PHP. I have to put the "index.php" file (my file indexer) in each of the folders so I can see the files in the current folder, which is cool.

Sadly, im able to see the file "index.php" in the list, a thing that I dont want to see.

I used the following to exclude the "index.php" file from the array of shown files:

```
$files = array_diff($files, ["index.php", "RESSOURCES"]);
```

(whoops, I lied. It also excludes the "RESSOURCES" folder.)

Sadly, the fact that I have to put the "index.php" in all of the folders is quite limiting. Its becoming a real problem since I have about a hundred folders and subfolders on there...

So my question is:

What can I put inside my .htaccess file so it solves my problem (im using apache 2.4)

I already tried putting:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /Home/index.php
```

But it always shows the files located at /Home/ instead of the files located *where* the error occured.

Any tips?

Cheers.

Comment: can we see your code for your indexer, not sure if .htaccess is the best solution for this

Comment: Its using glob() to show the files. It excludes "index.php" and "RESSOURCES" from the array and I added a foreach($files as $filename) so it generates a list of clickable files. If you need any more clarifications, please ask me. :)